# Bootstrap - 2 column form layout with fixed textarea height and column ordering

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

i'm trying to build a 2 column form layout in bootstrap with an fixed height textarea on the right. I got it working well on desktop screen with an `.pull-right-md` (own class) on the textarea box. But in "responsive" mode (on smaller screens) I have the problem with the order of the boxes. I want the textarea to be on the last position when displayed on small screens.. I already tried to solve this problem by ordering the col's with `.col-*-pull` and `.col-*-push` classes but it was not working.

Here you can see what I have done so far: http://www.bootply.com/BBFB4Tt97j

Do you have any ideas how I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plz don't ever do duplication of html elements for sake of styling, it's not worth it! You breaking semantics, and produce illogical code that is tricky to maintain.

You can easily achieve desired effect without duplicating anything:

http://output.jsbin.com/debenudiqi/2/

You can grab code here

http://jsbin.com/debenudiqi/2/edit

Answer (score 1):

This is what I suggest, tried to work my way around with pull and push but i haven't found a solution with that. You can use the hidden-xs, visible-xs to create two different text-area, one visible only on small screen and the other on large screens only. But you make sure when you handle the form, you handle the two different text areas.

```
<form class="">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group pull-right-md hidden-sm hidden-xs">
        <textarea class="form-control textarea-fixed-height" id="textarea" name="textarea">default text</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Email" type="email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Telefon" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Betreff" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 form-group pull-right-md hidden-lg hidden-md">
        <textarea class="form-control textarea-fixed-height" id="textarea1" name="textarea1">default text</textarea>
    </div>
</form>
```

---

### [Bootply link](http://www.bootply.com/BBFB4Tt97j#)

Comment: nice approach.. seems like this could solve my problem, thx!!

Comment: don't forget to handle the two textarea when you are submitting your form or checking for input from the user. if you consider this as the answer, you can mark it as answer too. :D

Comment: is marked as answer now ;)
and your note for submitting is interesting too.. do you think both textareas should have the same id/name for submitting on small aswell as on big screens? or would you give them two different id's for addressing in the ajax/php?

Comment: they should definetly have different ID/name. because the code sees both textarea and only the user doesn't see them so the best to do is to check if one of them has text in it. If one is not null then submit it because in no case, you will have the user submitting both only if he gets to the code and modifies it. On you can check what screen type on submit and just select the textarea depending on the screen type at submission. It all depends on you.

Comment: yes, sounds plausible. Will try to check the textareas for content and if it has it should be submitted.. hope I can do it because my js/ajax skills are not the best ;)

Comment: if you find a hit-wall whilst doing that, post another question. someone with greater skills will answer. or someone with an idea. :)

Comment: Plz don't ever do html element duplication for the sake of styling. Look at my answer. You always can do almost anything just by using CSS.

Answer (score 0):

So for everyone with the same kind of problem thats the solution of my problem: http://www.bootply.com/BBFB4Tt97j#

I have put two `textareas` in the `form`-tag. One as first box and the second on the last position but before the submit button. With `.hidden-xs` and `.hidden-sm` on the first textarea it's not visible for smaller devices and with `.hidden-md` and `.hidden-lg` I prevent the `textarea`-tag for showing up on big screens.

this is working fine now.. thx